# Tomcat setenv.sh customizing property

Tags: tomcat, jvm

I want to modifying xml file by VM options.

So i write setenv.sh like this.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Drun.my_own_property=my_own_value"
```

It is work well in my local server in intellij, but i'm afraid this make situation when real server or test server deploying with this option.

Can i customizing property in setenv.sh like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there `catalina.sh` in `[CATALINA_HOME]/bin` on your real server or test server?

If yes, did you run `chmod +x setenv.sh`?

`setenv.sh` is called by `catalina.sh` (, `daemon.sh` or `tool-wrapper.sh`). If  your real server or test server is CentOS or RHEL and Tomcat was installed by yum command, there are no `catalina.sh` and therefor `setenv.sh` is not called.

FYI, `export` is not needed in `setenv.sh`.

Comment: yes, OS is CentOS and tomcat was installed by yum but catalina.sh is exist and in catalina.sh as you know, it point out setenv.sh.

my question is not setenv.sh doesn't work.
Am i using own property and value like -Drun.my_own_property?
For thx export is not needed in setenv.sh, i'll try this later.

Comment: Customizing properties can be used in `setenv.sh` without any problems.